# Is it possible to test Spring REST Controllers without @DirtiesContext?

Tags: java, spring, rest, testing, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring-Boot web application. The usual way of writing integration tests is:

```
@Test
@Transactional
@Rollback(true)
public void myTest() {
    // ...
}
```

This works nicely as long as only *one thread* does the work. `@Rollback` cannot work if there are multiple threads.

However, when testing a `@RestController` class using the Spring REST templates, there are *always* multiple threads (by design):

- the test thread which acts as the client and runs the REST template
- the server thread which receives and processes the request

So you can't use `@Rollback` in a REST test.  The question is: **what do you use instead to make tests repeatable and have them play nicely in a test suite?**

`@DirtiesContext` works, but is a bad option because restarting the Spring application context after each REST test method makes the suite really slow to execute; each test takes a couple of milliseconds to run, but restarting the context takes several seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, testing a controller using a Spring context is no unit test. You should consider writing a unit test for the controller by using mocks for the dependencies and creating a [standalone mock MVC](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/setup/MockMvcBuilders.html#standaloneSetup-java.lang.Object...-):

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyControllerTest {
  @InjectMocks
  private MyController tested;
  // add @Mock annotated members for all dependencies used by the controller here
  private MockMvc mvc;

  // add your tests here using mvc.perform()
  @Test
  public void getHealthReturnsStatusAsJson() throws Exception {
    mvc.perform(get("/actuator/health"))
      .andExpect(status().isOk())
      .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status", is("OK")));
  }

  @BeforeEach
  void createControllerWithMocks() {
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
        // add custom error handler or there advice here:
        //.setControllerAdvice(new MyErrorHandler())
        .build()
  }
}
```

This even works if you use an external `@ControllerAdvice` for error handling etc by simply calling `setControllerAdvice()` on the MVC builder.

Such a test has no problems running in parallel and is much faster by no need to setup a Spring context at all.

The partial integration test you described is also useful to make sure the right wiring is used and all tested units work together as expected. But I would more go for a more general integration test including multiple/all endpoints checking if they work in general (not checking the edge cases) and mocking only services reaching out to external (like internal REST clients, replacing the database by one in memory, ...). With this setup you start with a fresh database and maybe will not even need to rollback any transaction. This is of course most comfortable using a database migration framework like [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org) which would setup your in memory db on the fly.

Comment: So, basically what you do is to call the REST controller methods directly without involving an application container (embedded or otherwise), is that correct? It's an interesting approach, thanks for the pointers. So you test your "entity-to-json" mapping separately? And you use larger, scenario-based integration tests for the entire application?

Comment: @Alan47 no, when using mock mvc in a unit tests, you will also test all mappings and you don't call the controller methods directly. Instead you use mvc.perform to create a mock request which is mapped against the controller including any (default) conversions and (default) message converters. If you need special things you have to decide not to test here or do more sophisticated MVC building (like adding HAL support or special conversion service setup).

Comment: Sounds great! I need to look into this MockMVC more in the spring docs. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried MockMVC in my application and it works like a charm, it's fantastic and so much better than the Spring REST template. Thanks for pointing this out to me, I always overlooked it because of the "MVC" part (I do not use spring-webmvc) so I thought this isn't what I need.

Comment: I alos use this appoach and have done since I dsocevered it. It does somewhat depend on your definition of unit test I've found; some.will say because you don't directly call the methods like with any other Java object test(which is doable for controllers), you're somewere between unit and integration testing, but I find it's easier to justify this kind of approach by thinking of it in terms of testing it's proposed usage; controllers aren't called like a standard method, and this is just a simulation of it real usage while still aligning with the core principles of a unit test

Comment: @ArneBurmeister: so.. would it make sense to test the controller, the wiring and mapping, but without actually using the attached service(s), but using mocks for the latter instead? Sure, I could then write an integration test, which includes the services, too, but wouldn't it just double my work with no advantage?

Answer (score 0):

Below is my implement followed by #4

```
private MockMvc mockMvc;
@Mock
private LoginService loginService;
@Mock
private PersonalService personalService;

@InjectMocks
private LoginController loginController;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(loginController).build();
}

@Test
void simple_login() throws Exception {
    Mockito.when(loginService.login(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()))
            .thenReturn(UserAccessData.builder()
                    .accessToken("access_token_content")
                    .refreshToken("refresh_token_count")
                    .build());

    mockMvc.perform(
                    MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/login/simple")
                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                            .param("accountName", "1234561")
                            .param("password", "e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e")
            )
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.tokens.accessToken", is("access_token_content")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.tokens.refreshToken", is("refresh_token_count")))
    ;
}
```